# What is the theory behind this PRNG?

Tags: c++, random, theory

```
__forceinline static int Random()
{
    int x = 214013, y = 2531011;
    seed = (x * seed + y);
    return ((seed >> 16) & 0x7FFF) - 0x3FFF; 
}
```

The code above returns PRNG with decent uniform distribution.

Now change x to x + 1 - resulting sequence couldn't be called PRNG anymore.

So what is the theory behind (this) PRNG? 'x and y are carefully chosen' but how does they were chosen?

Comment: [Normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)? Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: Fred Larson: I edited my post, sorry for my 'typo'. I wrote normal distribution because (if I think correctly) normal distribution is observed from real world, so a good PRNG should replicate a behaviour of normal distribution in order to generate a good random sequence? I'm I right about this? The generator is from here by the way http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-random-number-generator-on-the-intel-pentiumr-4-processor/

Comment: Some natural phenomenons are well modeled as a normal distribution.  Others, such as the throw of a dice, are not.

Comment: André Caron, Fred Larson: ok thanks, I just read about uniform distribution from wiki and I understand now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). A LCG is better when the multiplier `x` is divisible by all prime factors of the modulus minus one (which is `0x3FFFFFFFF` here, it's a bit hidden due to the math in the return statement).

Comment: the modulus is in fact 0x80000000 here. And it is x - 1 divisible by prime factors of m, not x divisible by prime factors of m - 1 (which is prime here)

Answer (score 4):

It is a 32-bit [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) which discards the lowest order 16 bits. I doubt this generator is good for interesting purposes. For simple games, this should be enough.

Your specific question is answered by the link I posted: the generator achieves full period with this particular y if and only if x - 1 is a multiple of 4 (in Wikipedia's notation, a is x, c is y and m is 2^31).

Hence, when x is even, the generator is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear congruent generator. There should also be a modulo; the
classic formula is:

```
seed = (a * seed + b) % m;
```

In this case, `m` is simply 2^n, where n is the number of bits in `seed`
(which presumably has an unsigned type, since modulo arithmetic is
needed).  There's extensive literature on how to choose `a`, `b` and
`m`; in general, according to the reference document (*Random Number
Generators: Good Ones Are Hard to Find*, Park and Miller, CACM, Oct. 
1988), `m` should be a prime number, and `b` can normally be 0; this
generator violates both of those rules.  (Violating the first tends to
make the low order bits very non-random, which explains why the results
are shifted.)

As far as I know, the only way to ensure that the choice of `a` and `m`
are good is to do extensive statistical tests, although there are ways
to identify some bad ones.  For starters, `a` and `m` should have no
common factors.  (In the best generators, both are typically prime.)
Here, `m` is a power of 2, and adding one to `x` makes it divisible by 2
as well, so you're more or less guaranteed that the resulting generator
will not be very good.

For more information, I'd suggest you read the article.

Comment: There is no way to chose a and m such that a LCG passes eg. Diehard tests. LCG should be avoided at all price.

Comment: @AlexandreC. There are better PRN generators, at least for the usual definitions of better.  For many applications, however, an LCG with carefully chosen `a` and `m` is sufficient, and it is usually a lot faster than the alternatives.  (For other applications, of course, it's not, and some other algorithm must be used.  LCG are not cryptographically secure, for example.)

Comment: James Kanze: thanks for the link and article. Alexandre C.: Particularly now I use this PRNG for generating white noise for my audio application. I really need very fast solution, which is the case with this PRNG, also I have not complains about noise it generates - seems good to me.

Comment: @Vadim: it depends on what you do with the noise. LCG have poor statistical properties, and there are modern statistically better alternatives which perform at least as well (XOR-shift for instance, see the work of Marsaglia). For numerical applications, I avoid LCG like plague since random vectors drawn from LCG tend to be totally non random.

Comment: Alexandre C.: I want to filter the noise to get a bunch of harmonics which have some width in themself - hence noise. Then I will reconstruct the waveform from the harmonics. Will this PRNG be sufficient? I don't have a try to do this for now, so I don't know if this PRNG will work. I will also check for XOR-shift now. If you have any recomendations or a source code which you know performs better and fast will be glad if you post it.

Comment: @Vadim: you can find well performing code in Numerical Recipes version 3 (in C++). The correlation structure of vectors drawn from LCG is horrible, and doesn't resemble white noise at all. See [the wikipedia entry for LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_LCGs)

Comment: To pick one nit, results are the same (on most machines) whether seed is int or unsigned int. Under 2's complement arithmetic, signed 32 * signed 32 always gives the same result (in the lower 32 bits) as unsigned 32 * unsigned 32.